# Как выравнить левый край title по центру кнопки?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Есть кнопки, в которых имеются картинки и тайтлы. Тайтлы с разным количеством символов. Так как изначально тайтл можно установить по левому краю кнопки, правому краю и середине кнопки, то из за разной длины тайтла в кнопках текст отображается не ровно относительно друг друга, что влечет за собой и смещение картинок

Пытаюсь выравнить текст и картинку каждой кнопки в сториборде методом тыка подгоняя по мм

но на одном размере телефона отображается идеально ровно, а на других размерах все плывет... Логично было бы привязать левый край тайтла в каждой кнопке к середине кнопки , а не весь тайтл к середине... Подскажите, как можно сделать? Или какие-нибудь др варианты есть?

Скриншоты к вопросу по ссылке, ТК вопрос публикую с мобилы, не могу загрузить скрины: https://forum.swiftbook.ru/t/kak-vyravnit-levyj-kraj-title-po-czentru-knopki/904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать одинаковые размеры картинок, настроить Title Edge insets, выравнивать по левому краю. Тогда текст будет аккуратно выровнен в кнопках по левому краю

Answer (score 0):

кроме вариантов вверху можно:
- сделай title с помощью своей UILabel и установи ее на button.superView
- сделать image с помощью отдельной imageView